# jsf+primefaces 3.1 printer issue

Tags: java, html, jsf, printing, primefaces

I am trying to run the primefaces printer example taken from their website
but the printer function is not working.
Below is my code.

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Print" type="button" >
        <p:printer target="image" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <p:graphicImage id="image" value="/images/nature1.jpg" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: i used same example using primefaces 2.2rc and it worked !!! whats the go now /

Comment: getting any error? have you migrate properly to 3.1 ? or it a new project? have you succeed using any other primefaces component?

Comment: no errors coming, I can use other components stuff like <p:password />

Comment: maybe something in the console of the firebug?

Comment: it says PrimeFaces is not defined

Comment: have you include the tag lib xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" ?

Comment: yup I did, do I need to specify something on the web.xml

Comment: I have <h:head> tag also

Comment: is it a from scratch project? or some old one (primefaces 2 version) that you upgraded?

Comment: I upgraded it, its was using  2.2 before, now I changd to 3.1 and <p:printer /> not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8636/discussion-between-eric-and-daniel)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<h:outputLink id="lnk" value="#">
    <p:printer target="image" />
        <h:outputText value="Print Image" />
    </h:outputLink>
<p:graphicImage id="image" value="/images/nature1.jpg" />
```

or like this

```
<h:commandButton id="btn" value="Print">
    <p:printer target="image" />
</h:commandButton>
<p:graphicImage id="image" value="/images/nature1.jpg" />
```

Comment: I created a new project and imported the primefaces jar 3.1.1 and add the prvious code. its not working, i dont know why its not coming, strange